# webscanner.nocache.js is not present in ephesoft

Tags: java, open-source, alfresco

I have installed ephesoft community version on my system and tried to work on to the web scaner.
But when i click on to the webscaner tab it shows me blank page and a error in to the console ie

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost:8082/dcma/webscanner/webscanner.nocache.js"

.

I have downloaded the source code of epchesoft from  https://code.google.com/p/ephesoft/
and tried to search webscanner.nocache.js in source code folder and havent found any thing.

Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

Web Based Scanning module is included in the Enterprise Edition only..
See below url
[Ephesoft Enterprise Edition and Ephesoft Community Edition Comparison](http://ephesoft.com/products/on-premise)